# Как сервер вычисляет Etag при скачивании файла

Tags: php

Как сервер вычисляет Etag при скачивании файла
какой алгоритм или какая функция это делает какие параметры файла участвуют в создании ETag

````
Server: ddos-guard
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2022 20:29:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 13063421
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 12:57:12 GMT
ETag: "10cd3c4-5a7a644121a00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 4554439-17617859/17617860
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Стандарт не регламентирует способ генерации etag: [rfc7232 - 2.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232#section-2.3.1)

> For example, a resource that has implementation-specific versioning applied to all changes might use an internal revision number, perhaps combined with a variance identifier for content negotiation, to accurately differentiate between representations.  Other implementations might use a collision-resistant hash of representation content, a combination of various file attributes, or a modification timestamp that has sub-second resolution.

> Например, ресурс, который имеет управление версиями, зависящее от конкретной реализации применительно ко всем изменениям может использоваться внутренний номер редакции, возможно в сочетании с идентификатором отклонения для согласования содержимого, чтобы точно различать представления. В других
> реализациях может использоваться устойчивый к столкновениям хэш содержимого представления, комбинация различных атрибутов файла или временная метка модификации с разрешением до секунды.

Если же вас интересуют именно конкретные реализации, то можно посмотреть это в исходниках [nginx](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/bfc5b35827903a3c543b58e4562db8b62021c164/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c#L1675) или [apache](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/21f16155c38e406e0a0daaa60a539d66128cf044/server/util_etag.c#L214).

Comment: меня больше нужно как это сделать у себя на компе если у меня есть только файл такую функцию куда передал имя файла и он сгенерил etag такойже как и сервер. тогда не нужно будет md5 файла где то на серваке хранить что бы и его проверять и проверке целостности файла

Comment: Для конкретных реализаций придётся узнать как настроен сервер, и уже на основе этого, реализовывать генерацию со своей стороны.